# SurfaceView gets dimmer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I'm currently using OpenGL to draw sprites on a texture laid on a `SurfaceView`. Everything works except for the fact that as soon as a sprite (which as of now is a simple 2D triangle built following Google's own developer tutorial) is drawn the `SurfaceView` gets dimmer. It happens only the first time and then it stays with that brightness layer. What am I doing wrong?